# Why does the read-only test work for a read-write file when using _access?

Tags: c++, c, posix, msdn

In a CPP application that uses some Microsoft file I/O functions, I came across some uses of the _access function which looks similar to a posix API.  It does not appear to be a standard C function.  To be sure I understand how it works, I wrote the following unit test function.

```
TEST_F(TestFileIOApis, FileReadWriteTest)
{
  const char* fileName = "newfile.txt";
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "w+");

  // It's rather strange to me that the read-only and write-only tests work this way
  // for a read-write efile.
  auto result = _access(fileName, 4);
  EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(errno, EINVAL);

  result = _access(fileName, 2);
  EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(errno, EINVAL);

  result = _access(fileName, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(errno, EINVAL);

  result = _access(fileName, 6);
  EXPECT_EQ(result, 0);
  EXPECT_EQ(errno, EINVAL);

  fclose(fp);
  fp = 0;
}
```

Perhaps the documentation is not worded clearly, but to me read-only means read-only, not readable.  Since I created the file as a read/write file I expected the test for read-only and write-only to fail.  That's obviously not how the Microsoft implementation works.  The posix documentation I could find about the access function doesn't describe the modifiers in the same way since unix / posix documentation uses constants such as F_OK, R_OK, and so forth.

As a follow-up: is the behavior that I see consistent with how it would work on a Linux machine as described here?
https://linux.die.net/man/2/access

The Microsoft documentation is here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-waccess

Comment: On POSIX systems, [the bits in the *mode* mask](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man3/access.3posix.html) are called `R_OK`, `W_OK` and `X_OK`; this makes it a little bit more clear that they check whether it would be OK to open the file for reading, writing or executing.

Comment: @AlexP: Yeah, but then to find out if you have two abilities, you should combine them with `bitor` not `and`.... `if (access(filename, R_OK and W_OK))` does not test what it suggests...

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's a bit mask. Of course you combine them with `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Linux `access` will work the same way.

The problem is in how you are thinking about "read-only".  Checking read-only access means

> Only check if I can read the file

not

> Check if I can only read the file

It's not looking for read-only permission, it is predicting whether opening the file in read-only mode will succeed.

Note that it doesn't actually do that right either; the documentation says that

> it does not check the filesystem security settings

which makes `_access()` completely worthless on Windows.

---

In addition, you seem to think that the `"w+"` argument to `fopen` when creating a file has some influence on later `_access()` calls.  It does not.  `access()` is testing a filename for what mode you could use when opening it, not testing an open handle (Linux equivalent: file descriptor) for what mode it is open with.  The permissions on a newly-created file are affected by the permissions of the directory it is in and your umask, not the initial mode.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you're right about the stream state.  I would have to use _chmod to setup the read write bits for access checks to work.  However, how could it be worthless on windows if Microsoft implemented it?  Why would one implement a worthless function?  I'm not sure if I buy that yet, but I'll test a bit more and see what happens.

Comment: @shawn1874: One reason to implement a worthless function is so that code written to use it (perhaps it was made first for Linux) will compile and run.  In the particular case of `access()`, which is just about useless on any OS due to the TOCTOU problem, simply returning success in all cases probably makes a lot of software work, while leaving out the function would cause link errors.

Comment: After performing a full set of unit tests, chmod and access seems to work fine on windows.  After clearing up the misunderstanding about what read-only means, my tests are working now.

Comment: @shawn1874: Did you test with files the current user doesn't have permission for, or just toggling the readonly attribute?

Comment: Just toggling the read / write attributes with _chmod.  it looks like the legacy code I was trying to figure out uses _access only to determine if a file exists.  Occasionally _chmod is used to set the read only bit.  The code does not seem to do anything with permissions or security attributes.